# Find mismatch cells in a column based on the date column of two dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that are not equal in their length.
df1

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 12-4-2020 | Nan |
| 13-4-2020 | 30 |
| 18-4-2020 | 20 |

df2

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 10-4-2020 | 40 |
| 13-4-2020 | 30 |
| 18-4-2020 | 11 |
| 20-4-2020 | 14 |
| 22-4-2020 | 71 |

I want to extract the dates on df2 with mismatched prices of df1 based on the date column. For example from the tables above, I should obtain this:
13-4-2020.
I need to:

- ignore any all df2 dates that are not exist on df1.
- count number of dates exist in df1 but not exist in df2

As the price of the same dates are mismatched in df1 and df2 (20 , 8)

`df3['Answer'] = np.where(((df1['Date'] == df2['Date']) & (df1['price'] != df2['price'])) , True, False)`

But I got this error:
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (4128,), (4715,))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with remove rows with missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), add `indicator=True`, so possible filter dates in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df1.dropna(subset=['price']).merge(df2,on=['Date','price'], how='left',indicator=True)

out = df.loc[df['_merge'].eq('left_only'),'Date'].tolist()
print (out)
['13-4-2020']
```

If need filter all columns use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out1 = df[df['_merge'].eq('left_only')]
print (out1)
        Date  price     _merge
0  13-4-2020   20.0  left_only
```